# fseek - stream does not support seeking - .flv file

Tags: php, flv

Here is my code:

```
$fd = fopen($url, "r");

if ( isset($_GET['start']) )
{
    fseek($fd, intval($_GET['start']));
}

while(!feof($fd))
{
    echo fread($fd, 4096);
    ob_flush(); 
}
```

But I get error: Warning: fseek() [function.fseek]: stream does not support seeking in (...)

How I can use fseek to parse .flv file?

Answer (score 1):

Copy it to a local filesystem first. (With "local" meaning a filesystem on the same server that's hosting your php script). Then open the local copy, and you should be able to call `fseek()` on it. As the saying goes, "you can't seek() on a pipe"...the main difficulty being that you can't rewind a pipe (or a socket)
if you need to move the file pointer backward.

Comment: Why I should copy it on local filesystem? I want use this script on my web hosting server.

Comment: I meant "local to the web hosting server", as opposed to opening a socket to some other host using the URL, and trying to process it that way.

Comment: OK, but I can't copy this file on my local server because this file weight more than 1GB. I would like to parsing a many files in one time using this script so I can't download all this files on my server because my server has only 500MB free space. Is another way to do it? Maybe I can use another function?